# React Native Custom Scrollable Tabbar with Dynamic Content

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, native-base

I want to create a tab bar in React Native that has the following characteristics:

- Custom UI (Custom Tab Styling AND a "create tab button" at the end of the tab bar)
- Scrollable (More Tabs then width can take)
- Dynamic Content (a click on a button IN the tabbar creates a new tab)

[image: Custom Scrollable Tabbar with Dynamic Content]

Pressing the button should create another tab at the end of the tab list.

I tried [Native base Tabs](https://docs.nativebase.io/Components.html#tabs-def-headref), but there I cannot place the button in the tab bar. I also tried doing it with [React Navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/material-top-tab-navigator.html) but struggle overwriting `tabBarComponent` and especially using the position parameter to visualize the active tab and animate between tabs.

Question: **How can this be done in React Native? Is there some example somewhere?**

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `scrollView` and `TouchableOpacity(button)`.

If I make what you want, I use Scrollview, so I can scroll **horizontally**.

And add buttons in Scrollview with using `map` or something, so there is buttons as much as I want.
(If you just want static number of button, just add buttons.)

If you want to go somewhere, just add function in the map components.

Plus, the last button, I add seperately in Scrollview.

So there can be simple code like,

```
<ScrollView horizontal={true}>
    {this.state.list.map((item, i) => (
        <TheButtonYouWant/>
    ))}
    <AddButtonYouWant/>
<ScrollView>
```

**+edited**

I wasn't thinking about that. I have an idea.
You can divide the screen into two. One is main screen, Second is tab screen.

So when one of your tab's component is clicked, show indexed screen by changing `state`.

It must be working, but I don't know it is best way to visualize what you want.

I hope it helps you

Comment: Yes, I think that could work. One thing missing though is the swipe effect between tabs: Normally with tabs I can swipe left and right and see the other tabs view during swiping. How do you add that? Since I think this might be quite some effort with this manual ScrollView approach is there some way using react navigation for that?

Comment: Hi, thanks. I think this will work, but it will not have the same look and feel like a real tabview, where you can swipe and see the neighboring tabs content while swiping.

Comment: @user2500558 I know what you want. I think you can use `Animated` of react-native.